# Which framework / toolkit is suitable for a pool-like iPhone / iPad game?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing an iPhone / iPad game that is like pool. I started with cocos2d 0.99.5 but can't find everything I need.  I would like to have:

- collision of multiple balls and reflection in other directions with certain angles
- moving striker beyond touch point and deceleration in effect of collisions and rebounces
- amount of force applied through striker which should depend on finger swipe distance

CCMoveTo & CGRectIntersectRect aren't enough. I found that I further need either chipmunk or box2d, considering loads of physics and mathematics involved.

What framework or toolkit do you recommend for doing this, and how should I proceed?

Comment: You state you've tried Cocos2D, but you're not using either of the available physics engines. Me confused. :-)

Comment: The field of iPhone game engines is quite active and there are many to choose from that have good physics libraries built in. I have prepared a listing of [all known iPhone game engines](http://mobilegameengines.com/iphone/game_engines) that might help you find an alternative to Cocos2D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what problems you've experienced, but [Cocos2D for iPhone](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) really does sounds like the ideal solution as it's based on a established framework ([Cocoa2D](http://cocos2d.org/)), is Objective-C "native", OpenGL ES accelerated and offers out of the box support for both the [Chipmunk](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics/) and [Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/) physics engines you mention.

Additionally there are quite a few [tutorials out there](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial) to get you started on the basics, [some of which use Box2D](http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls) if you're having problems getting the various physics objects set up/mapping them to their on-screen counterparts.

Comment: thanku for your quick response. Yes, i am already following Ray and am through the basic tutorial. i am now digging cocos2d with Box2d deeper. Still if you come across with anything as direct solution or tips, please do add it here as it'll just help me speedup things :)

Comment: @WJK To be honest, Cocos2D and Box2D will make it about as easy as it gets, so I'd persevere along this route. (Or perhaps ask a specific question about using Cocos2D/Box2D if you get stuck.) Incidentally, there's also a dedicated Stack Exchange site (http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) for game development issues that might come in handy. Hope it goes well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

what about using cocos2d + Box2d physics engine¿¿?? it's already included in the cocos2d distribution